# Wrap extension function into another

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin

I want to simplify my code.

I have implemented a way to hide the soft keyboard when I touch the screen using a SearchView.

I show you the code...

**Call** (inside an activity where sv is an instance of a SearchView)

```
hideKeyboard(this, sv)
```

**Fun extensions**

```
fun Activity.hideKeyboard(context: Context, sv: SearchView) {
    hideKeyboard(HideKeyboardWithSearchView(context, sv))
}

fun Activity.hideKeyboard(hideKeyboard: HideKeyboardWithSearchView) {
    window.decorView.rootView.setOnTouchListener { _, _ ->
        hideKeyboard.start()
        return@setOnTouchListener false
    }
}
```

**And the class to perform the action**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager

class HideKeyboardWithSearchView(private val context: Context, private val sv: SearchView) {

    fun start() {
        val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(sv.windowToken, 0)
        sv.clearFocus()
    }
}
```

I would like to merge the two fun extensions in one. I think this should be easy with a lambda or similar, but I do not control very well this part of the language... :-(

Any idea? :-)

---

**SOLUTION**

Solved by [rya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9241978/pawel) and [Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9241978/pawel).

```
fun Activity.hideKeyboard(sv: SearchView) {
    window.decorView.rootView.setOnTouchListener { _, _ ->
        HideKeyboardWithSearchView(this, sv).start()
        return@setOnTouchListener false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need to pass `Context` into `Activity`s extension (aside from few special cases).

Second, I don't really see how you want to merge them into one? Unless you mean removal of second extension all together, in that case your first method should simply contain the body of second one:

```
fun Activity.hideKeyboard(sv: SearchView) {
    val hideKeyboardSV = HideKeyboardWithSearchView(this, sv)
    window.decorView.rootView.setOnTouchListener { _, _ ->
        hideKeyboard.start()
        return@setOnTouchListener false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I totally agree with your advice about not to pass the Context. I do not know what I was thinking... :-D

Answer (score 2):

you could just use the second one like this:

```
fun Activity.hideKeyboard(sv: View) {
    window.decorView.rootView.setOnTouchListener { _, _ ->
        HideKeyboardWithSearchView(this, sv).start()
        return@setOnTouchListener false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!